# Displays' sound output not appearing since the latest software update

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I had a software update popup a couple of days ago, installed everything and can't choose either of my 2 displays as the sound output device. It doesn't appear at all. There's only Line out (which is for my headphones), there used to be another 2 menu items to choose from. Doesn't appear in settings either.
How do I fix this?

Comment: What is the version of your Ubuntu system? What is the output of `uname -rv`?

Comment: @FedKad 5.19.0-1018-lowlatency #19-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Feb 7

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue. Starting with an older kernel (from 5.19.35 to 5.14.0) fixed this.

You can select an old kernel in the grub menu. Press shift after the UEFI menu appeared. After that, go to the advanced options and there you can choose the kernel.